# Can you shrinkwrap some vertices in edit mode?

Tags: modeling

Hope the title makes sense.

I have a highly detailed mesh and I want to shrink wrap a very small part of it (that's connected to the rest) around a cylinder.

Comment: Detach them into a separate object, shrinkwrap them and join it again.

Comment: While in edit mode, you can you snap tool to vertices, edges, faces or volume. It might suit what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to assign the fragment to some Vertex Group and use that group in Shrinksrap modifier.Like this:
[image]